# dnf - verbose output (where are files installed?)

Tags: fedora, package-management, dnf

The problem I have with package managers is that they don't tell where they install all the files.
For example when I install the package `fzf` with `apt` files get stored in **different locations** as when I install the same package with `dnf`.
`dnf` might put some files in `/usr/share/fzf`, maybe a config folder in `~/.config/fzf` or in `/etc/fzf/`...

But how do I know **where** exactly the package manager installs **all** those files, what symlinks it creates and what it does exactly, like a verbose output?
So I don't have to search my entire file system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m not aware of an option to list files as they are installed, but you can ask the package manager for a list of files, either after installing:

- `rpm -ql fzf`
- `dpkg -L fzf`

or before:

- `dnf repoquery -l fzf`
- `apt-file list fzf`

Answer (score 1):

You could use Midnight Commander to examine RPM/DEB files (simply <kbd>Enter</kbd> into them) - not only it shows files, it also shows scripts (pre/post update and uninstall) and it's all a breeze to view.

You could also use 7-Zip under Wine/in Windows. It can open RPM files and show their contents (they are partially comprised of a [CPIO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cpio) archive). DEBs are compressed [AR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_(Unix)) archives.

Lastly you could use rpm2cpio in conjution with cpio.